# Finding corresponding coordinate based on known ordered pair

Tags: functions, graph-theory

[image]

I need to know how to find the corresponding `Y` coordinate based on a given `X` coordinate that lies between two ordered pairs.

Example:

`(60,25)` and `(70,40)` Find the `Y` coordinate that corresponds to a `X` coordinate of `65`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is a straight line between two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, then the corresponding value for any $x$ is this equation

$y = y_1 + \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}(y_2-y_1)$.